# charAt() on HTML entities

Tags: javascript, unicode, emoji, html-entities

Say I have the following HTML code:

```
<span id="test">&#128138;</span>
```

If I do `document.getElementById('test').innerHTML.charAt(0)` I get � back. Is there a way to get the actual glyph back?

Here's a JS fiddle showing the code in action:

https://jsfiddle.net/mLznfxr7/